# Filling the tag wiki and getting reviews

Tags: discussion, tags

If we need 4000 points to edit the tag wiki then who is editing and approving them at the moment? I added [transforms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transforms) and [dimensioning](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimensioning) to experiment with how that works. My edits have not been reviewed, who do I contact or do those edits appear in a community officer dashboard?

I get the impression from the tag wiki documentation that it can be a great place to have in-depth coverage of topics. In addition to the excerpts, we are encouraged to go into detail -- i guess we will arrive at some consensus on how much detail.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone with **1500+** rep can [approve tag wiki *suggestions*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). It usually takes *2* approvals from normal users for one to pass through and 1 from a SE mod.

Users with **4000+** rep can [*edit* tag wikis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) without any approval. Also, you don't normally contact anyone, these are added to the *Suggested Edits* queue and will be addressed once seen.